# How to find first three digits matching pattern from a single column between two text files

Tags: python, regex, bash, shell, awk

I would like to match first three digits (ex: 132******) from a single second column($2) between two text files. Could anybody suggest me the script to do this?.

Input file1:

```
9 73316991 73352391 DEL 99 35401
9 96058269 96059400 DEL 99 1132
9 132186937 132206288 DUP 99 19352
9 138338172 138339132 DEL 99 961
```

Input file2:

```
9 132185894 132209127 DUP 99 23234      
9 140495212 140496044 DEL 99 833 
9 136625162 136626293 DEL 99 1132
```

Output file3:

```
9 132185894 132209127 DUP 99 23234
```

Comment: We will not do your work for you. Type `man grep` into your bash and see if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[substr($2,1,3)];next} substr($2,1,3) in a' file1 file2
9 132185894 132209127 DUP 99 23234
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. Also, is it possible to search the same kind of pattern among five different files as an input?, that would be really helpful.

Comment: It is possible but you cannot add a new problem via comment. If this answer works out then you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: did you try adding 3 more filenames behind *file1 file2*?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{key=substr($2,1,3)} NR==FNR{a[key];next} key in a' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thank you very much!.   Also, is it possible to search the same kind of pattern among five different files as an input?, that would be really helpful.

Comment: The answer to "is it possible?" is always "yes".